# How to solve this problem with N unknowns and N equations?

Tags: calculus

Suppose that we have, $\forall i \in N$, where $|N|<\infty$:
\begin{gather*}
u_i=x-\left[(1-\rho)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{|N|}\sum_{j\in N}^{j\neq i}u_j+\frac{1}{|N|}\left(x-\alpha_i\right)\right)+\rho\cdot\mu_i\right]\\
u_j=x-\left[(1-\rho)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{|N|}\sum_{i\in N}^{i\neq j}u_i+\frac{1}{|N|}\left(x-\alpha_j\right)\right)+\rho\cdot\mu_j\right]\\
...\\
...\\
...\\
u_n=x-\left[(1-\rho)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{|N|}\sum_{n\in N}^{i\neq n}u_n+\frac{1}{|N|}\left(x-\alpha_n\right)\right)+\rho\cdot\mu_n\right]
\end{gather*}

Further, $\rho\in(0,1]$; and everything except the vector $\mathbf{u}\equiv(u_i)_{i\in N}\equiv(u_i,u_j,...,u_n)$ is known. My goal is to identify each element in $\mathbf{u}$ as a function of the known parameters, but not as a function of other unknown elements of $\mathbf{u}$. Because we have $|N|$ equations and $|N|$ unknowns, I assume that the problem can be solved, but I just don't know how.

Thus, my question is two-fold: **what is the solution to the problem above and how do we reach it?** Additionally, could anybody please tell me what kind of problem is this and how one usually goes about facing it? Some external resources (for ***beginners***) would also be really appreciated.

Thank you all very much in advance for your time and your effort.

Comment: What is $N$?  How is this different from just using indices from 1 to $N$ for some positive integer $N$? Have you tried writing this in matrix-vector notation?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. $N$ is just a set with $|N|$ elements indexed by $i$. It probably differs in nothing with respect to just using indices from $1$ to $N$. However, my field is not mathematics and this is the notation I'm used to. I'm sorry if it was confusing: feel free to edit my question as convenient. And no: I haven't tried writing this in matrix-vector notation. Where would this lead me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write the system in matrix-vector form.  That is you want to write it the form $Ax=b$ where $A$ is an $n\times n$ constant matrix, that is, every element of $A$ is known, $$x=\pmatrix{u_1\\u_2\\ \vdots\\u_n}$$ and $b$ is a column vector of $n$ elements.

Then if $A$ is invertible, $\boxed{x=A^{-1}b}$  If $A$ is not invertible, then either there is no solution, or there are infinitely many.

It is not usually possible to find a closed-form formula for $A^{-1}$ except in very special cases.  If you are looking for a formula, I suggest you try to find one in the case $n=2$ to start and see if you get any insight.  If you are simply interested in a numerical solution, then there are lots of computer systems that will compute the answer for you, even when n is rather large, say $n=1000,$ or probably much more these days.

I don't mean to imply that it's necessary to compute the inverse in order to solve the system.  There are more efficient ways.  I would expect that finding a closed-form formula for the solution would entail finding a formula for the inverse, but I suppose it might be possible without that.

It's hard to give you any more advice unless you give more context.  What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have stated my goal in my original question: namely, "to identify each element in $\mathbf{u}$
 as a function of the known parameters, but not as a function of other unknown elements of $\mathbf{u}$. I don't know how to explain it better. Also, I found a closed-form solution when $|N|=2$, and I can perfectly find one for when $|N|=3$. The thing is: how do I generalise from there to an arbitrary $N$? I thought there would be some systematic way to do so, but I suspect from your words that I need to do a particular induction exercise, right?

Comment: @Héctor Yes, you did say what you wanted.  I forgot by the time I had written my answer, sorry.  You should edit this question to put in the solutions for the $n=2$ case and for the $n=3$ case, if it's available.  Induction might not be necessary.  If we can guess the general form, we might be able to prove it directly.  In fact, I think this is more likely to work than induction.

Comment: I just noticed that the question I posted is not the real question I have. I posted sooner than I had to (namely, before thinking). I'd really like to delete the answer, but that would deprive other people from the knowledge you shared with me here, so I was advised not do so. Anyway, I accepted the answer. Thank you very much for everything.